# Apache HttpClient 4.2.1 POST request to fill form after successful login

Tags: java, apache, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing an application which can log in to a site and submit a certain form.
I can successfully log in, but when I try to sent another POST request to submit another form, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
    try {
           //log in to site
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.ru");
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "guest"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "guest"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

           //all ok. i obtained cookie
        List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                ConnectionManager.printLog("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

            //then trying to fill another form in another page of this site
        httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.ru/?h[0][mode]=controllers&h[0][action]=add&h[1][mode]=controllers");

        List<NameValuePair> nvps2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner", "0"));
        nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", "123456789123456"));
        nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "asdfghj"));
        nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type_id", "6"));
        nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remarks", ""));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps2));

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           //after filling this form, site must redirect me on another page. 
        entity = response.getEntity();
           //but then I look on page I obtained, it's still the same page with form I tried to fill. 
           //It seems like I didn't post request.
        String pageHTML = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println(pageHTML);

        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

The second form doesn't differ from first by type.

Comment: Try enabling wire logging and make sure your form is being submitted as expected: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Same problem with me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. In second form (not the login form) there was submit Button:

```
<form method="post">
   <p>...<p>
   <p>...<p>
   <p>...<p>
   <p>...<p>
   <p>...<p>
     <input type="submit" name="apply" value "Save">
</form>
```

To fill the form, save and go to the next page I should add one more `ValuePair` to my post request:

```
nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apply", "Save"));
```

I don't know why I didn't need to send such a Button value to log in when I filled the authorization form. But now all is working!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Was facing the same problem myself . Thanks again. :)